# DNS redirect to website directory

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, redirect, rewrite, 301-redirect

We've currently got one DNS record connecting to many web applications in IIS through DNS Made Easy. eg.

*myDNSName.example.com/Customer1*

*myDNSName.example.com/Customer2*

This worked fine because the *myDNSName.example.com* was pointing to one box. Now we are in the situation where we need to spread these websites over multiple boxes. We'll cop major issues if we require the customer to hit a different link since they will need to propagate this down to all their users.

Is there a way we can setup the mappings at the DNS level to point *myDNSName.example.com/Customer1* to one IP address and *myDNSName.example.com/Customer2* to another IP address? The current way that I'm thinking that we could achieve it would be to write a website redirect/rewrite at the IIS level but that means IIS becomes a fail point that if that central box doing the redirects goes down then all go down. Wanting to make sure we have a separation of concern so we limit the chance of one thing failing taking everything down with it.

Comment: You can't "point" DNS to a URL.

Answer (score 4):

No, DNS is not aware of http, so you can't point it at a server based on URL.

You can point DNS at a load balancer, such as Nginx, and have it proxy the request to other servers. If you want redundancy you could look into two A records for the load balancer and run two of them in [round robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS). In theory, if one load balancer is down the other could be used, but I don't know if this will work in practice. The client might always use the first A record, it might use them 50/50, it might fail over first to second, etc. It's worth considering as it's the cheapest option, but once again, I haven't tried this.

A better option could be a managed service, such as AWS ELB (Elastic Load Balancer). However your have to be in AWS (Amazon Web Services). An ELB needs a CNAME record in DNS, rather than an A record.

AWS [Route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) DNS is an advanced DNS service that can effectively distribute requests to different servers. You can split traffic by percentage, you can failover, you can do geographic or latency based balancing, and you can use a combination of those. It's probably your best option.

Another option could be to use [CloudFlare CDN](https://www.cloudflare.com/), who can do [load balancing](https://www.cloudflare.com/load-balancing/) for you across multiple servers. This is a practical option. Call them to ask if they can help. You'll likely need one of their paid plans. There are likely to be many other providers who can do this, I just happen to know CloudFlare does.